# Does new Cassandra node should be fully data-populated and cluster be rebalanced before accepting user based read/write queues?

Tags: cassandra

We have a stable Cassandra cluster with heavy nodes of 4TB each. What will happen when another 4TB node is added - will it start to accept requests immediately, or only when the full cluster rebalance will finally finish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are [adding nodes to a cluster following the proper steps](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsAddNodeToCluster.html), the new node will *not* accept client requests until the join/streaming operations are complete.

The only time that would happen, is if `auto_bootstrap` was set to `false` on the new node.  Then, the node would join without streaming data, and attempt to service requests before the data could be successfully streamed (via `repair`/`rebuild`).